# Wired Connection keeps disconnecting when plugged in

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am running an ubuntu 12.04 which i freshly installed , my wireless connection works fine but as soon as i connect wired network it disconnects after a couple of seconds. My wired connection is connected to a cisco switch. I tried giving it an ip manually and after a while it still disconnects...I installed ubuntu on a Windows PC but uninstalled the windows OS before installing

Answer (score 0):

You can not use two network connections at the same time without setting up routing rules.

That is why your wireless network disconnects as soon as you connect to a wired network.

Default route changes to wired network.

Comment: its rather the wired connection that disconnects anytime its plugged in

Comment: I do not quite understand your posts. If you disable wireless network, wired will work. If you disable wired, wireless will work. @AlfredAmonAfutu